# Paper Scroll Header Panel not working with Custom Element

Tags: polymer

I'm newbie at Polymer.

**Problem:**
I want use paper-scroll-header-panel in my custom element. Trying, but background image does not appear. Update: [Problem with images on Imgur](http://imgur.com/a/r1gEx)

---

**Files:** index.html, salon-header.html

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="salon-header.html">
<head>
<body>
    <salon-header></salon-header>
<body>
<html>
```

salon-header.html:

```
<dom-module id="salon-header">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-scroll-header-panel/paper-scroll-header-panel.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-media-query/iron-media-query.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-scroll-header-panel/demo/sample-content.html">
    <template>
    <style>
        paper-scroll-header-panel {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            background-color: var(--paper-grey-200, #eee);
            --paper-scroll-header-panel-full-header: {
                background-image: url(bg3.jpg);
            }
            ;
            --paper-scroll-header-panel-condensed-header: {
                background-color: var(--google-yellow-500, #f4b400);
            }
            ;
        }
        paper-toolbar {
            background-color: transparent;
        }

        paper-toolbar .title {
            font-size: 40px;
            margin-left: 60px;
        }
        .content {
            padding: 8px;
        }
    </style>
    <paper-scroll-header-panel condenses>
        <paper-toolbar class="tall">
            <paper-icon-button icon="arrow-back"></paper-icon-button>
                <div class="flex"></div>
                <paper-icon-button icon="search"></paper-icon-button>
                <paper-icon-button icon="more-vert"></paper-icon-button>
                <div class="bottom indent title">Title</div>
            </paper-toolbar>
            <div class="content">
                <h3>Resize window to toggle between fixed header and scrolled header</h3>
                <sample-content size="100"></sample-content>
            </div>
        </paper-scroll-header-panel>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'salon-header'
    });
</script>
```

---

This works in a single file. But i want seperate files to clean index.

**I tried:**

- Put webcomponentsjs only index and only salon-header. In the same way
  all of these imports.
- added attiribute to style tag in
  salon-header.html like:  (Likewise demo
  files.)
- Changed dom-module and template tags includes. Example: I put
  the styles inside template or outside. Same way Imports inside
  template and outside.

---

**Finally:** In this project structure (In question), header not have background image, only have background color #3f51b5.
 
When i try other ways, sometimes header doesnt appear, sometimes header have transparent background (Inherited from body: #eee)

---

I hope, i can explain myself.

---

By the way, you can share with me your Polymer experiences and you can  suggest me Polymer tips. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `<style>` tags outside the `<template>` element. Please see the relevant documentation [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html). Same with adding external stylesheet. You should add it before the `<template>` tag and inside the `<dom-module>`

Comment: Thank you sincerely. I am already using the documentation, but this was very helpful.

I'd tried lot of combination, outside inside etc etc but every time i used 'Sublime Text - Html-Css-Js Prettify' extension. And it broke my style codes. Figured out it now. Thanks, again.

Comment: This changed again to `<style>` inside `<template>`

Comment: @Aravind is it possible at all, to bind a polymer value with the value of a background-image in the `<style>` tags so that we can have a variable background image